# R version 3.5.1 Installation Error: MCDM and OutrankingTools

Tags: r

When I tried to install

install.packages("MCDM")

or

install.packages("OutrankingTools")

to R, it gave a warning message as the following:

```
> install.packages("MCDM")
```

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/nilde/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘gtools’, ‘RankAggreg’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/gtools_3.8.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 325812 bytes (318 KB)
downloaded 318 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/RankAggreg_0.6.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 364390 bytes (355 KB)
downloaded 355 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/MCDM_1.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 52916 bytes (51 KB)
downloaded 51 KB

package ‘gtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘RankAggreg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘MCDM’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\nilde\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCuBcMX\downloaded_packages
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘yaml’

How can I install and start to use these two packages?

Comment: Since you received an error related to `tools`, try installing `devtools` using `install.packages("devtools")` and then load `library(devtools)` before trying to reinstall these packages.